# Two accompanying class hierarchies - a good design pattern?

Tags: c++

Is the following a good design pattern in C++?

```
    Pet               PetOwner
     |                   |
 ---------         --------------
 |       |         |            |
Cat     Dog     CatOwner     DogOwner
```

In other words, **two accompanying class hierarchies**. Have you seen this done, and is it considered a good practice?

Let me clarify further. This design certainly follows the "open-closed" principle. It is "open" in the sense that new things can be added easily (new `Horse` and `HorseOwner` subclasses), and it is "closed" in the sense that new things can be added without modifying existing code.

The purpose of these two accompanying hierarchies is that, for example, `PetOwner` has a `feed()` virtual function, and `Pet` has a `make_hungry_sound()` virtual function. Also, `Cat` is constructed with a particular `CatOwner`.

Is there a better design pattern that can replace two related hierarchies like these? The reason I'm asking is that I'm wondering whether it's considered a good practice to require people to add **two classes at the same time** when extending things. Seems a bit dubious...

Comment: it depends on the reason for the parallel hierarchies. i think your reason is ungood. also, just the idea of making `CatOwner` a distinct type is ungood.

Comment: Dogs have owners, but cats own humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a highly subjective question. Answers can be many (and more if you add more info to the question) so I'll just comment based on what's available in the question:

Assuming the `PetOwner` has more to do than just `feed()`, yes, it's justified to have it. E.g. you won't breed every pet, you won't put every pet in a beauty contest.
If all `PetOwner` has to do is feed, just one concrete class is enough.

Answer (score 0):

To give my opinion, no, the design for pets is there but the pet owner has no reason to be specific and would end up being ambiguous/over complicated. It would be a better design to create a pet owner that could hold all types of pets, then create functions that relate to all pets.

```
//in class petOwner
pet *animal;

//user wants a dog...
animal = new dog; //you now have a dog
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just have a PetOwner and double dispatch feeding on pet and it's subclasses. A pet knows what he has to eat. Implement feeding on pet.